# C++ For loop loops only 299 times

Tags: c++

I'm having this weird problem. My code is simple:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    cout << "number: ";
    cin >> num;

    for (int i=0;num>i;i++) {
        cout << i <<"\n";    
    }

system ("Pause");
return 0;    
}
```

If the input for example is 1000, the output contains numbers from 701-999.
Any idea?

I'm using Dev-C++ IDE on Parallels.

Comment: Maybe output is lost in the command window? Run this program with output redirected to file, or increase command window history.

Comment: Use a \t or a space instead of \n, everything will be visible.

Comment: sounds like you are using cygwin. Change the bufffer size to 9999 (or is the max 99999)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually it prints all of them, from 0 to 999, but your console's buffer is not large enough. So you see only the last part. if you print into a file, not the console, you'll see :)

Answer (score 10):

The loop ends when `num>i` is no longer true. This occurs when i is 1000, so the last loop executed will be with value 999.  As for not seeing lower than 701, maybe your screen buffer is too small.

Comment: Smells Windows: 300 lines is the cmd.exe's default max of vertical lines.

Answer (score 5):

It will start with 0-999. Also, it appears to you that it starts with 701 because of your console screen settings. If you want to see it for yourself, change the newline into a space:

```
cout << i <<" ";
```

Answer (score 3):

Did 0-700 scroll off the screen? Run your exe like this

```
your_program > out.txt
```

Then look at out.txt in an editor.

Answer (score 2):

Works absolutely fine for me. I'd suggest your IDE might be playing tricks on you. Could you redirect output into a file and check that?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding @JoshD answer,
You will need to:

```
 for (int i=0;num>=i;i++) {
    cout << i <<"\n";    
}
```